# How do I automatically switch to one subversion repository if another one fails?

Tags: svn, controls, version

I have a subversion repository on a network shared folder. It is not a subversion server, just a disk that multiple computers can read and write to.

Different computers map network drives in different ways. How do I make it so that if svn can't find the folder on one path it automatically tries another?

Or more generally, how can you specify a list of locations to commit to?

Comment: How will you keep them in sync?

Comment: This does not seem sane. How are these repositories kept in sync if one of them goes offline? You'd be better off doing this with a DVCS like Git, no? Otherwise I don't really see how there's any way to keep the development history...

Comment: Make a real server. Network shared folders do not have locks, and so keeping a repository there is a bad idea--something will break sooner or later.

Comment: I work in 2 different labs (on my own code) and, while I am provided with a network share between my different computers, I am not provided with a way to host a whole subversion server.  I am not worried about locks, since I am the only one writing the code.  If you want, you can pretend that there are 2 servers automagically synced via a strong connection, and 1 user trying to commit via a weak one that periodically drops out.

Comment: This sounds like you should use a DVCS. Git or Mercurial are probably the answer. SVN is really not built for this, and any solution involving it is going to be a hack at best.

Comment: How would you do this in Git?

Comment: About how to do it in Git: You set up multiple remotes (AKA remote/tracked repositories). You can then "push" one or all of your branches to one or all of these remotes. Remotes can have paths on the local filesystem (file://) or supported protocols (ssh://, git://, ftp:// ...). More documentation is available in the man pages of git-push and git-remote, as well as on the 'net.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't something that's easy to do. File systems aren't set up for it, and most applications desire a hard failure when something's missing. Subversion is really designed to have a single, master place that it commits to.

It really sounds like you either need to run an always-available SVN server, or switch to a different version control system. The former is the standard use case, and what most subversion tools are set up for.

It's slightly unclear what you're doing, but another alternative might be to set up a post-commit hook (again you'd need a server to do this) that would update, export, or check out the repo to various points on your network whenever a commit happens.

If you were willing to look at alternatives, Git and Mercurial are the two big distributed version control systems which are probably better suited to your needs.

http://git-scm.com/

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/

Answer (score 0):

On Windows SVN is able to check out files from a remote server. Say your file server is `fileserver` , your share is `files` and the path is `foo\bar\baz` (You can type `net use` in a cmd window to show the server/share mappings of your network drives). So your repository is `\\fileserver\files\foo\bar\baz`. Then you check out a working copy from the server path `file://fileserver/files/foo/bar/baz`.